# Can you use a dash to separate two complete sentences?

Tags: dashes

The term was from her party days - she always looked for a way to incorporate party slang into our lives.

Should there be a dash there?

Comment: The two bits are related—an *em dash* like that works fine. But if you mean a hyphen, that's not quite it (though okay in a text or other passing stuff). In Word, use Ctl-Alt-(the minus sign on the number pad) to generate the em dash.

Answer (score 0):

It's OK, if you want a little extra drama.  Otherwise, I would use a semicolon in that particular sentence. In Word on a Mac use Option+Shift+hyphen for an em dash.